# Device not showing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, usb-debugging

I am using android studio 3.3.2 and try to test the app on mobile device. I am using haweii mobile. i try to find the solution but nothing help me. I found a lot if solutions on stack but these solutions did't work? Is there any one who could help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1- connect mobile to system
2- allow permissions
3- go to  mobile settings
4- go to about
5 -then click 7 time on build number
developer mode will on
then there will be development option
go their and click USB debugging on
Hope so it will wok for you

Comment: i am able to test the app on samsung mobiles but it is not working in haweii